# How to get minimum date by each section for same id different times? - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, minimum

I use SQL Server 2012. I have some table with daily history for delay sum, something like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD
GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testsum](
        [CID] [int],
        [HDATE] [date],
        [DELAYSUM] [numeric](16, 2)
)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testsum] ([CID], [HDATE], [DELAYSUM]) VALUES
        (223,'2016-10-16',15503.80)
        ,(223,'2016-10-17',15493.82)
        ,(223,'2016-10-18',15489.25)
        ,(223,'2016-10-19',15417.08)
        ,(427,'2016-10-01',10375.89)
        ,(427,'2016-10-02',10375.89)
        ,(427,'2016-10-03',10385.91)
        ,(427,'2016-10-16',8448.57)
        ,(427,'2016-10-17',8443.13)
        ,(427,'2016-10-18',8440.64)
        ,(427,'2016-10-19',8401.31)
        ,(427,'2016-10-20',8411.20)
        ,(427,'2016-10-21',8414.58)
        ,(427,'2016-10-22',8414.58)
        ,(427,'2016-10-23',8414.58)
        ,(427,'2016-10-24',8401.23)
        ,(427,'2016-10-25',8393.92)
        ,(427,'2016-10-26',8379.14)
        ,(427,'2016-10-27',8374.57)
        ,(427,'2016-10-28',8358.67)
        ,(427,'2016-10-29',8358.67)
        ,(427,'2016-10-30',8358.67)
        ,(427,'2016-10-31',8346.61)
        ,(541,'2016-10-05',900.44)
        ,(541,'2016-10-06',832.84)
        ,(541,'2016-10-11',637.54)
        ,(541,'2016-10-15',413.89)
        ,(541,'2016-10-16',413.89)
        ,(541,'2016-10-17',413.89)
        ,(541,'2016-10-18',1728.12)
        ,(541,'2016-10-22',265.27)
        ,(541,'2016-10-23',265.27)
        ,(541,'2016-10-24',265.27)
        ,(541,'2016-10-25',787.10)
        ,(541,'2016-10-26',1222.29)
```

Example data for 3 ids in October:

```
    CID         HDATE      DELAYSUM
    ----------- ---------- ---------------------------------------
    223       2016-10-16   15503.80
    223       2016-10-17   15493.82
    223       2016-10-18   15489.25
    223       2016-10-19   15417.08
    427       2016-10-01   10375.89
    427       2016-10-02   10375.89
    427       2016-10-03   10385.91
    427       2016-10-16   8448.57
    427       2016-10-17   8443.13
    427       2016-10-18   8440.64
    427       2016-10-19   8401.31
    427       2016-10-20   8411.20
    427       2016-10-21   8414.58
    427       2016-10-22   8414.58
    427       2016-10-23   8414.58
    427       2016-10-24   8401.23
    427       2016-10-25   8393.92
    427       2016-10-26   8379.14
    427       2016-10-27   8374.57
    427       2016-10-28   8358.67
    427       2016-10-29   8358.67
    427       2016-10-30   8358.67
    427       2016-10-31   8346.61
    541       2016-10-05   900.44
    541       2016-10-06   832.84
    541       2016-10-11   637.54
    541       2016-10-15   413.89
    541       2016-10-16   413.89
    541       2016-10-17   413.89
    541       2016-10-18   1728.12
    541       2016-10-22   265.27
    541       2016-10-23   265.27
    541       2016-10-24   265.27
    541       2016-10-25   787.10
    541       2016-10-26   1222.29
```

Need output (minimum date for each section of dates in ids (CID) with end date for each period (section))
Segments are separated by 1 or more days:

```
    CID         HDATE      DELAYSUM    END_DATE
    ----------- ---------- ---------------------------------------
    223       2016-10-16   15503.80    2016-10-19
    427       2016-10-01   10375.89    2016-10-03
    427       2016-10-16   8448.57     2016-10-31
    541       2016-10-05   900.44      2016-10-06
    541       2016-10-11   637.54      2016-10-11
    541       2016-10-15   413.89      2016-10-18
    541       2016-10-22   265.27      2016-10-26
```

Stuck with this task for now.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to classify the records per cid into the same group if the date difference between consecutive rows is 1. This query uses a logic `dateadd(day,-row_number() over (partition by cid order by hdate),hdate)` to do it. Run the inner query to see how the groups are assigned.

Thereafter, using window functions `min`,`max` and `first_value` you can get the min hdate, max hdate and first value of delay sum per cid using the groups previously assigned.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cid,
                min(hdate) over (partition BY cid, grp) AS hdate,
                first_value(delaysum) over (partition BY cid, grp ORDER BY hdate) AS delaysum,
                max(hdate) over (partition BY cid, grp) AS end_date
FROM (SELECT t.* ,
      dateadd(DAY,-row_number() over (partition BY cid ORDER BY hdate),hdate) AS grp
      FROM testsum t ) x
ORDER BY cid,hdate
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/ZPC27232)

Answer (score 0):

One method for solving this is the difference of row numbers:

```
select cid, min(hdate), max(hdate), min(delaysum)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by hdate) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by cid order by hdate) as seqnum_c  
      from testsum t
     ) t
group by cid, (seqnum - seqnum_c);
```

EDIT:

As I look closer, it looks like you want the first value, rather than the minimum value.  SQL Server doesn't offer `first_value()` (yet) as an aggregation function.  So:

```
select cid, min(hdate), max(hdate), min(first_delaysum)
from (select t.*,
             first_value(delaysum) over (partition by cid, seqnum - seqnum_c order by hdate) as first_delaysum
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by hdate) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by cid order by hdate) as seqnum_c   
            from testsum t
           ) t
     ) t
group by cid, (seqnum - seqnum_c);
```